# Split delimited string in one column and keep other column intact

Tags: sql-server-2008, dbo

My table data is as follows

```
x------x--------------------x
| Key  |        Ids         |
x------x--------------------x
|  1   |    23,34,45,56,78  |
|  2   |    56,76,45,7,98   |
x------x--------------------x
```

I would like the output to be like

```
x---------------x
| Key  |   Ids  |
x------|--------x
|  1   |   23   |
|  1   |   34   |
|  1   |   45   |
|  1   |   56   |
|  1   |   78   | 
|  2   |   56   |
|  2   |   76   |
|  2   |   45   |
|  2   |   7    |
|  2   |   98   |
x------x--------x
```

I know to use `dbo.split()` but don't know to combine and show. Please advise

Comment: _Don't store data like that!_ You should store this data as you described the output in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CROSS APPLY to do this. Here's an example but you'll need to tweak the column names depending on your Split function:

```
SELECT a.Key, b.Data from YourTable a
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(a.Ids, ',') b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do without `Dbo.Split`.

Here is your sample table

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP 
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 [KEY],'23,34,45,56,78' Ids
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'56,76,45,7,98'
)TAB
```

Here is the query

```
SELECT [KEY],PARSENAME(REPLACE(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),'-','.'),1) 'Ids' 
FROM  
(
     SELECT [KEY], CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Ids, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
     FROM #TEMP     
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/005c1/2)**

Now if you want to use `dbo.Split` itself you can use the above code.

```
SELECT a.[Key], b.items
FROM TEMP a
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(a.Ids, ',') b
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00370/1)**

[image]